# Nhibernate Queryover subquery and whereexists with 2 conditions

Tags: .net, fluent-nhibernate, queryover

Consider the following object structure.

```
Product
id : int
name : string
attribute : list of Attribute

Attribute
id : int
name: string
value : string
product_id : int
```

The questions is:
Using QueryOver how to form a subquery to return all products
with the following conditions:

Select all products where when have attributes at the same time:

Attribute name = "Color" Value="Red"
and
Attribute name = "Size" Value="XXL" ?

*Edit:* Sample sql:

```
select * from Product p where
exists (select id from attribute where name = 'Color' and value = 'Red' and product_id = p.id)
and
exists (select id from attribute where name = 'Size' and value = 'XXL' and product_id = p.id)
```

Comment: How would you write this query in sql?  That's how I usually start out unless you aren't familiar with sql.

Comment: It would need to have a subquery for each attribute. The performance will not be good.

Comment: @Roland: Yes, could you write the SQL you want? That will make the question much easier to answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using a subquery which counts the attribute matches is the easiest IMO

```
Product productAlias = null

// get the count of matching Attributes
var subquery = QueryOver.Of<Product>()
    .Where(p = > p.Id == productAlias.Id)
    .JoinQueryOver(p => p.Attributes)  
        .Where(a => (a.Name == "Color" && a.Value == "Red") || (a.Name == "Size" && a.Value == "XXL"))
    .Select(Projections.RowCount());

// get the Products where all match
var results = session.QueryOver(() => productAlias)
    .WithSubquery.WhereValue(2).Eq(subquery)
    .List();
```

The subquery can be shortened if there is a Property Product on the Attribute class

Comment: I cant see this overload. What version is that in ? .Where(2, subquery)